# Access Data (Selected) in a ListView QML/Qt

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I'm accessing a XML page (online) via a XmlListModel and displaying the data using a ListView delegate (Row).

Once the Listview display the data (Xml file always only contain one "record"), i want a separate label to display one of the node's data (selected row)? Any guidance on this matter is appreciated.

My Listview:

```
ListView {
id: viweID
model: modelID
delegate: Row {
    id:rowID
    spacing: 10
    Text {
        id: fnameId
        text: FName
         }
    Text {
        id:lnameID
        text: LName
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` can be accessed either in terms of its items or by visiting its underlying model (see the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) for further details).

It looks to me that you want to visit the former, for it already contains all the data that have to be shown on your separated panel.
To do that you can rely on the `currentItem` property and the signals `onCurrentItemChanged`/`onCurrentIndexChanged`.
It's a matter of exposing the desired properties from the delegate object to be able to read them and set them on the other panel.
See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html) for further details on how to expose those properties.